# calculate mean of numpy array based on unique element of another array

Tags: python, numpy

```
m = np.array([[[1,2],[2,1]], [[1,1],[2,1]]])

array([[[1, 2],
        [2, 1]],

       [[1, 1],
        [2, 1]]])



m2 = np.array([[[0.4,0.5],[0.2,0.3]], [[0.3,0.4],[0.5,0.5]]])

array([[[ 0.4,  0.5],
        [ 0.2,  0.3]],

       [[ 0.3,  0.4],
        [ 0.5,  0.5]]])
```

How can I calculate the mean of `m2` for each unique element of `m`? I could write a list comprehension to loop through the elements of `m`, but I was wondering if there was a more straightforward way to do this. Is `np.ma.masked_array` appropriate in this case?

This is what I'm trying to achieve

```
1: np.mean(m2[m==1])
2: np.mean(m2[m==2])
```

this is fine for a couple of elements, but if I have 100, then it becomes cumbersome. I could write a list comprehension, but was hoping for a better alternative.

Comment: Could you include an example code of what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: To further the previous comments, it's not clear to me at all how `m` and `m2` are related

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I have updated the question with an example

Answer (score 1):

```
[np.mean(m2[m==i]) for i in np.unique(m)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas give you a fast and elegant solution :

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame(index=m.ravel(),data=m2.ravel())    
df.groupby(level=0).mean() 

#      0
#1  0.38
#2  0.40
```

it runs in 30 ms with:

```
m = np.random.randint(100,size=(100,100,100))
m2 = np.random.random((100,100,100))
```